# how to update the templateCache in angularJs

Tags: angularjs

`angular.module('genTemplates', [])
               .run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) { 
                    $templateCache.put('admin-article.html', '<div>......</div>'); 
        ......
}]);`

> ok,i am new to angularJs. what i puzzled is, i've changed the content in admin-article.html but the value of the key 'admin-article.html' remain unchanged....,maybe there are some tools needed to do this?i need your help - - !

Comment: If you want to change the template content after adding it to cache, you need to do it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
$templateCache.remove('admin-article.html');
```

Make sure you are actually having problems with $templateCache, you can open inspector in Chrome, click on the 'Network' tab and refresh the page. You will be able to tell then if it is actually loading your updated template or not.

Comment: Thank you for your enthusiastic response. my problem fixed because i find the template updated by the tool gulp....

Comment: Glad to hear you figured it out!